# Error running '__rvm_make -j 1'

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew

Today I was trying to install ruby 2.5.0, but I am getting this error every time.

**console output with the error I got**

```html
rvm install ruby-2.5.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-2.5.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/andreiaalmeida/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.5.0 - #downloading ruby-2.5.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13.3M  100 13.3M    0     0   429k      0  0:00:31  0:00:31 --:--:--  490k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.5.0 - #extracting ruby-2.5.0 to /Users/andreiaalmeida/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.0....
ruby-2.5.0 - #configuring......................................................|
ruby-2.5.0 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.5.0 - #compiling...

Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
please read /Users/andreiaalmeida/.rvm/log/1519558776_ruby-2.5.0/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

**My make.log file**

```html
[2018-02-25 11:40:33] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/andreiaalmeida/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.0
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/andreiaalmeida/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/andreiaalmeida/.rvm/bin
command(3): __rvm_make -j 1
++ make -j 1
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens   -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin17 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/10.0.0
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/andreiaalmeida/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/libruby.2.5.dylib -compatibility_version 2.5 -current_version 2.5.0  -fstack-protector -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector -framework Foundation  
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc 
    LANG = 
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
compiling miniprelude.c
translating probes probes.d
error: error reading '/dev/fd/4'
1 error generated.
clang: error: unable to remove file: Operation not permitted
dtrace: failed to compile script probes.d: Preprocessor failed to process input program
make: *** [probes.h] Error 1
++ return 2
```

I tried to completely uninstall rvm (rvm implode) and reinstall it but I wasn't successful.

**System**

- Mac OS X – High Sierra (10.13.3)
- rvm 1.29.3 (latest)
- Homebrew 1.5.4

Comment: I also have this exact problem. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `rvm install 2.5.0 --disable-dtrace`

the reason is here, https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1061,

possible Ruby build problem

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I had to run "rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles" before this, because I had had path error. thanks for the answer, this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue as the original poster.

Compilation would halt at

```
ruby-2.2.6 - #compiling...                                                                                                                   
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',                                           
please read /Users/alexharvey/.rvm/log/1525652818_ruby-2.2.6/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Inspection of the make.log revealed:

```
translating probes probes.d
error: error reading '/dev/fd/4'
1 error generated.
clang: error: unable to remove file: Operation not permitted
```

I finally found this reference to Avira Anti-virus in [this](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4313) link.

I went to Avira Anti-virus and selected "disable real time protection" and tried again. That fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

For M1 processors:

Right click Terminal from the Application/Utilities folder, Get Info, and tick the "Open using Rosetta" box.

Uninstall Homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/*
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

Reinstall Homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Restart terminal

Check Homebrew is working fine: `brew doctor`

Reinstall openssl: `brew install openssl`

Install Ruby: `rvm install 2.5.0`

It is a copy-paste from Github: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5146#issuecomment-967048308

Comment: Running brew upgrade and opening terminal with Rosetta did the trick

Answer (score 0):

ruby-2.4.6 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/mgq/.rvm/log/1557891511_ruby-2.4.6/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

It seems that Avira antivirus is running. It has been reported to cause failures on ruby compilation.
Disable it for the time of the installation and try again.

#### make.log

- __rvm_make:0> make -j4
- '****************'
- error: error reading '/dev/fd/7'
- 1 error generated.
- clang: error: unable to remove file: Operation not permitted